# PowerShell Form Close Outputs "Cancel"

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I'm working with a PowerShell form and it has a red X close button in the corner. I don't want to disable this red X button, but when it is clicked it outputs

```
Cancel
```

to the script pane. How can I get this to not output to the script pane?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what is returned from the `ShowDialog()` method. If you don't want what's returned, you can either cast to `[void]` or pipe to `Out-Null`

```
$Form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```